# UWP app based on XamlNavigation Sample fails Certification

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, terminate, wack

I have a UWP app released in Store which I updated with a new UI based on the XamlNavigation sample. The updated app runs well on my development machine (x64) and passes WACK but fails Certification when I try to publish in store for silently terminating on launch. I cannot reproduce the failure on my dev machine but it does fail if I sideload it to another device (x64). Remote debugging on the 2nd device shows the following error before terminating during launch:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8FAB25EAB (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in xxxxxx.exe.5472.dmp: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x000002473325E280, 0x0000000000000003). occurred

I am using VS 2017 and compiling with .NET Native tool chain. I have reduced workload during launch, targeted different Win 10 versions, even removed and reloaded VS 2017 and Win 10 SDKs, all without success. Would appreciate suggestions as to what could be causing the failure?

As suggested below, I have tried to compile with .NET Native unchecked but get the following errors:

> The command ""C:\Users\xxx.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.2\tools\x64\ilc\tools\Gatekeeper.exe" @"C:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\xxxx\xxxx\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"" exited with code 1000.

and

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\XXXX.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.6.2\tools\x64\ilc\lib\Facades'.

**Update 20 May 2017**

If anyone is interested I have found the error that caused the failure - I had made a change in the AppShell.xaml file for the hamburger icons that worked on my dev machine but which the .NET native tool chain didn't like for some reason (still unknown). I can now find a different way to implement my changes. Also the Nuget issues were cleared by unchecking 'Enable static analysis for .Net Native' in Project Properties.

Comment: For "Certification for silently terminating on launch" did you meet this exception when you are trying to publish your app to store? For "Remote debugging on the 2nd device shows the following error before terminating during launch:" could you please test again with .Net Native took chain opinion unchecked?

Comment: Have edited above in answer to your suggestions. How can I fix Nuget issue?